# Extract UNIQUE fasta sequences from a text file

Tags: fasta

I have a TXT file:

```
HISEQ1:105:C0A57ACXX:2:1101:10000:105587/1 
HISEQ1:105:C0A57ACXX:2:1101:10000:105587/2 
HISEQ1:105:C0A57ACXX:2:1101:10000:121322/1
HISEQ1:105:C0A57ACXX:2:1101:10000:121322/2 
HISEQ1:105:C0A57ACXX:2:1101:10000:12798/1 
HISEQ1:105:C0A57ACXX:2:1101:10000:12798/2
```

and a fasta file with sequences:

```
>HISEQ1:105:C0A57ACXX:2:1101:10000:105587/1 
GCACCCTCGGGGGAGCAACGAAGAGGTAGACGAAGGCGATCGCAGCCACCTGCGGCAGTATCCCCAGGAGGTCAAGGTCCTCCTCCCCGCTCACCGTCGCC
>HISEQ1:105:C0A57ACXX:2:1101:10000:105587/2
TTGGTGGCAGGCAACAGCTTTGGACGGCCACCGCCTCATGGCGCCTCCTCCCCGCTGCGTCCTCGCCGCGTCCCTCCCTGCTTCAAGC
>HISEQ1:85:D0C0FABXX:5:1101:1385:36009/1
TTTAGTTCCAGGCCGGCTGAAGACTGTCTTTACAAAAGAAAAGTTTAGCCTAGGAAGCCCATTGTTGTAGGTGTTGTAGTTTTATAGATGTACTTTGGAAA
>HISEQ1:85:D0C0FABXX:5:1101:1385:36009/2
CAGCCAAGTTCGCAGTCTCGATAGTATTGTTTTCATACAGCAGTCTTGACAAACCAAAGTCCGCAACTTTTGGTTCCAGATTATCATCTAGCAATATGTTT
>HISEQ1:105:C0A57ACXX:2:1101:10000:105587/2
TTGGTGGCAGGCAACAGCTTTGGACGGCCACCGCCTCATGGCGCCTCCTCCCCGCTGCGTCCTCGCCGCGTCCCTCCCTGCTTCAAGC
```

I would like to extract the sequences of these ID's only once  from the fasta file and get this output:

```
>HISEQ1:105:C0A57ACXX:2:1101:10000:105587/1 
GCACCCTCGGGGGAGCAACGAAGAGGTAGACGAAGGCGATCGCAGCCACCTGCGGCAGTATCCCCAGGAGGTCAAGGTCCTCCTCCCCGCTCACCGTCGCC
>HISEQ1:105:C0A57ACXX:2:1101:10000:105587/2
TTGGTGGCAGGCAACAGCTTTGGACGGCCACCGCCTCATGGCGCCTCCTCCCCGCTGCGTCCTCGCCGCGTCCCTCCCTGCTTCAAGC
```

but I get also dublicates.
I tried these:

```
seqkit grep -f in.txt in.fa > out.fa 
seqtk subseq in.fa in.txt > out.fa
```

How to modify the command line above to get unique sequences?

Comment: Are you sure you are working with a fasta file? You should explain what is a fasta file to the audience. Give sample input and expected output for anyone to test answers. Also, if you are having problem with your code, you should explain which problem are you having and which are the errors you are seeing.

Comment: I explained better what are the formats. Regarding explaining the problem I gave a clear explanation, I do not get any error messages.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue. With your `seqtk` command I'm getting the expected sequences (given the fact that your second fasta sequence have two `>` symbols at the beginning, so it is not matched because the name is effectively different).

Comment: could it be the problem with duplicates?c'mon >> is just a typing error...

Comment: Yes, I tried, if the same sequence seen twice it will print it as well... while I need only unique...I'll modify the question now

Comment: Could be. BTW, your input file sometimes contains spaces at the end of the IDs, sometimes not. This could cause some mismatches.

Comment: Did you check the `seqkit rmdup` tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
seqkit grep -f in.txt in.fa | seqkit rmdup -n -o out.fa
```